# Tools to see ext2/ext3/ext4/btrfs/jfs/xfs filesystems under windows?

Tags: linux, windows, compatibility

Are there any drivers/application that can read/write ext2/ext3/ext4/btrfs/jfs/xfs filesystems from Windows?

E.g.: a removable drive is formatted with EXT3.. how can I write it under Windows XP/7?

Comment: I've brought this up on meta for [a discusion on whether it's "ontopic"](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/622/29) If you'd like to defend it from being closed.

Comment: `explore2fs` is another tool that I used in the past for exploring ext2 and ext3 filesystems from Windows. Provides nice navigable, explorer feel like UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got multiple tools for this :

- [FS-Driver for ext2/ext3 (freeware)](http://www.fs-driver.org/)
- [DiskInternals for ext2/ext3,ext4, ResiserFS (shareware )](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)
- [Ext2FSD (freeware)](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)
- [Crossmeta for native XFS, EXT4 ext2/3 ReiserFS](http://www.pavitrasoft.com/crossmeta.html)
- [Btrfs](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs)

Comment: ext2fsd and crossmeta are opensource. the ext2fsd and crossmeta links are gone, there are https://github.com/matt-wu/Ext3Fsd  and https://github.com/crossmeta/cxfuse

Answer (score 1):

Just for ext2/ext3 and ext4(only reading) [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)

```
Features Ext2Fsd supports:
ext2/ext3 volume reading & writing
ext3 journal replay when mounting
various codepage: utf8, cp936, cp950 …
mountpoint automatical assignment
large inode size: 128, 256, …
large file size bigger than 4G
CIFS sharing over network
htree directory indexing
ext4 extent read-only, no  size truncating and expanding support
Fast fsck (uninit_bg) and group block checksum support
64k block-size, support compatible to Linux ext4 and e2fsprogs
OS: 2k, xp, vista, server 2003/2008, win7
```

Answer (score 1):

[Captain Nemo Pro](https://www.runtime.org/captain-nemo.htm) reads XFS. It's not free though.