# How to remove existing Linux system on a hard drive, turn it into a normal disk, but keep some user files?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, nas

I just shucked a WD MyCloud for its hard drive. There are already around 5TB data on it. After ssh into the disk, I found there is a Linux system on there, which is not surpise since it was designed to server as a NAS.

I could copy all my 5TB data to another hard drive and format it. But that will take some time. So I wonder is there a way I could do, to convert this disk to a normal disk, without moving existing data on it. By normal, I mean when you connect it to another computer, it will just show as a disk with folders and files on it.

Thank you!

Comment: If you simply connect the HDD into another computer - it should show all the files in it. The only possible issue is the difference in the partitioning. If you are using Linux machine to see the content of the HDD - it probably just work straight away (since the HDD is most likely Ext3 / Ext4 formatted). If you have Windows machine - it may think the HDD is not formatted - and ask if you want to format it. Can you confirm what OS is on your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I wonder is there a way I could do, to convert this disk to a
> normal disk, without moving existing data on it.

Installing Linux makes your disk bookable by installing boot-loader and linux system files are stored pretty much like a normal disk holding files. So **nothing to convert** ; All you can do is - remove boot-loader files {simply delete boot folder} and EFI entry (assuming UEFI) {[how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi)}.

You can **simply delete Linux-related system files manually** . Keep the **home directory** if you want your personal data.

> By normal, I mean when you connect it to another computer, it will
> just show as a disk with folders and files on it.

Your disk will appear as a normal disk {with files and folders} on Linux OS. But you will not be able to access them in Win due to unsupported file system. To overcome you can simply **install ext4/ext3/btrfs or other needed win drivers** for win to access them {[tools-to-see-ext2-ext3-ext4-btrfs-jfs-xfs-filesystems-under-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/375967/tools-to-see-ext2-ext3-ext4-btrfs-jfs-xfs-filesystems-under-windows)}.

Answer (score 0):

No. It would seem the disk is using an ext or other "non windows" filesystem, and you cant convert filesystems in place (at least not to fat or ntfs).

**Its probably best to copy, format and copy back**, but depending on the filesystem and block layer config you might be able to shrink the filesystem slightly , create a new VFAT system at the end of it and put some tools to read a Linux fileststem from Windows on it.  A horrible hacky cludge though.